# Simh networking on openbsd?

Tags: networking, tcp, openbsd, openvms

I've setup OpenVMS 7.3 on simh under OpenBSD 5.8 (running as a vm under virtualbox). I have tcp working using a bridge on OpenBSD and I can access tcp services on simh from within the OpenBSD host vm. But I can't access simh from anywhere else on the network. Both OpenBSD and simh have their own IP address, which are standard to the physical network scheme since the OpenBSD VM is set to bridged mode.

OpenBSD is 192.168.1.220 and OpenVMS is 192.168.1.230

Is it possible to route traffic through the OpenBSD vm to the simh vm? I thought since they had their own unique IPs it would be possible.

Comment: I use a tap device on Linux Debian (it should be similar with BSD), and have the following configuration when starting for the network card in simh

`set xq enabled
set xq type=DELQA
attach xq tap:tap0`

Comment: Can you access the simh emulator from other pcs on the network? I can access it on the openbsd host, but nowhere else.

Comment: Yes, from several Debian and OpenVMS, using Decnet and IP

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it on Centos using bridging. Works great now.